# Xcode 9.3 crashes on deleting entity

Tags: xcode, xcode9.3

I got this crash when trying to reset the parent of the entity or delete one.

This is the crash report

```
    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 9E145
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEPlugins/IDEPlugins-14133/IDECoreDataModeler/ModelEditor/EditorShared/XDDiagram/XDDiagramStorage.m:364
Details:  (graphic) should not be nil.
Object:   <XDDiagramStorage: 0x7fa373ec1b50>
Method:   -removeGraphic:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa36a619650>{number = 1, name = main}
```

[image]

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong or if this an Xcode bug how do I avoid this crash?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, this is obviously another annoying bug in Xcode 9.3. Xcode 9.4 beta 1 still contains this bug.

Workaround: Right click on your .xcdatamodel file, show the package contents and edit the file `contents`. It contains the entity relationship model as XML file. You can delete the entity there, it's fairly simple. Remember to delete its relationship occurrences in the other entities as well.

Comment: Still happens (sometimes) on Xcode Version 12.3 (12C33)

Answer (score 1):

### Xcode 13 (if you are using `.xcworkspace`):

1. remove properties and relationships in the entity
2. remove relationships in other entities pointing at the entity you'd like to remove
3. quit Xcode
4. open the project from `.xcodeproj`
5. remove the entity

Comment: This worked in a .xcodeproj as well.